# How to create new lead in Salesforce using ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, salesforce, visualforce

I want to create lead, View lead, Update lead of SalesForce using ASP.net C#.
I have read many many blogs and confused. I am confused between development.salesforce.com, Force.com, APEX, Visual Force. Using which app i can integrate API for Pull/Push lead in salceforce.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From C# you have two common ways to integrate with Salesforce:

1. Use the Partner API. Import the Partner WSDL and make the required SOAP callouts.
2. Use the REST API. Make JSON based requests and parse the responses.

Of course, there are a range of libraries to make these tasks easier if you don't want to do them from first principles.

Have a look at the [Force.com Toolkit for .NET](https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-Toolkit-for-NET). There are also whole heap of [Nothing But .net posts](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/author/smorgan) on the developers blog that cover most of the basics.